# Need some help to convert JSON string to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

How do I convert this NSString to NSDictionary? Below is the NSString:

`NSLog(@"urlstring: %@", urlString);`
outputs: `urlstring: "{"url":"http://mydomain.com/metaioman_target.png"}"`

Then I convert it to JSON and then to NSDictionary:

```
NSData *json = [urlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:json options:0 error:&e];
```

However, when I `NSLog` the `dic` it is null, and printing the error gives the following:

```
error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" 
(JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) 
UserInfo=0x16641de0 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with 
array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

However, overwriting the `urlString` with:

```
@"{\"ID\":\"Content\":268,\"type\":\"text\"},\"ContractTemplateID\":\"Content\":65,\"type\":\"text\"}}"
```

converts it successfully.

I guess something is wrong with the quotes?

Comment: The `NSLog` should output => `urlstring: {"url":"http://mydomain.com/metaioman_target.png"}`, so your problem is the outer double quotes, get rid of them and it will deserialize just fine.

Comment: @Alladinian is right. Try converting after removing outer double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your string was valid (in terms of JSON) `NSLog` should output:

`urlstring: {"url":"http://mydomain.com/metaioman_target.png"}`

so your problem is the outer double quotes, get rid of them and it will deserialize just fine.

Comment: Yes. That was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have double quotes around the actual JSON string.
You need to check when these quotes are added and get rid of them.

`urlString` should be `{"url":"http://mydomain.com/metaioman_target.png"}` instead of `"{"url":"http://mydomain.com/metaioman_target.png"}"`

Or you can remove them before you deserialize:

```
[urlString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, [urlString length]-2)]
```